# DAML :- Am unable to set party as observer from another template of its array argument, please help on the same

Tags: daml

I am trying to set a party as observer, with that observer argument taking from another template argument which defined as array. Please find the below snippet of my code:

```
template Roles
  with
      subscriber: Party
      signeddate : Time
  where
    signatory subscriber
template Deal
  with
    deal: Users_Deal
    actor : [Roles]
  where
    signatory deal.agent
    observer actor.subscriber     <---  here I am getting an error

template Users_Deal
  with
    dealId: Text
    agent: Party
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the error it will look something like this

```
No instance for (DA.Internal.Record.HasField "subscriber" [Roles] a0)
arising from a use of ‘DA.Internal.Record.getField’
```

What the compiler is trying to say here is that the type `[Roles]` does not have a field called `subscriber`. This is correct. `Roles` has a field but `[Roles]` is a list of those types.

What you can do is to get the `subscriber` of each `Roles` (you might want to call it `Role` instead of `Roles`) in the list and set all of those as observers. You can do that by calling `map` on the `actor` list:

```
template Deal
  with
    deal: Users_Deal
    actor : [Roles]
  where 
    signatory deal.agent
    observer map (\a -> a.subscriber) actor
```